# Popup notification for microhone mute

Tags: windows-7, audio, script

I need to create a script or a batch file to show a notification-like balloon (or a message or icon)  when my microphone is muted and unmuted. I understand this can be achieved by task scheduled but I can't figure out what its event ID or source is.

I am using **Nircmd** to mute and unmute the mic, but I need a notification for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [trayballoon](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/trayballoon.html) in Nircmd for displaying popup notification. Create a batch file like in example given below and run it.

> start "" "**path to nircmd.exe**" mutesysvolume 0
>
> start "" "**path to nircmd.exe**" trayballoon "Mic" "mic is on " shell32.dll 10000